# Ícone de visibilidade de senha aparecendo, quando não deveria ser exibido

Tags: flutter, dart, login, icons

Estou fazendo uma tela de login e nela vou deixar a opção de tornar ou não a senha visível.
Eu já tenho tudo configurado, mas por algum motivo aparece um segundo botão que eu não criei. Não consigo identificar de onde ele é gerado e por qual motivo.
Queria saber se há algum código por trás (talvez nos widgets) o qual cria automaticamente o botão, e se há como configurar para removê-lo.

```
Widget _buildPasswordTF() {
    return

      Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Senha',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          height: 60.0,
          child: TextFormField(
            validator: (input) => input!.length <3
                ? "Senha muito curta"
                :null,
            obscureText: hidePassword,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.lock,
                color: Colors.white,
                ),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed:(){
                  setState(() {
                    hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                  });
                },
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                icon: Icon (hidePassword? Icons.visibility_off: Icons.visibility)
              ),
              hintText: 'Digite sua Senha',
              hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Aqui é a parte onde eu crio a tela:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xFF9A73F5),
                      Color(0xFF8761F1),
                      Color(0xFF7047E0),
                      Color(0xFF5339E5),
                    ],
                    stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Form(
                key: globalFormKey,

                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 40.0,
                    vertical: 120.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'WT Cloud',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      _buildEmailTF(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30.0,
                      ),
                      _buildPasswordTF(),
                      _buildForgotPasswordBtn(),
                     // _buildRememberMeCheckbox(),
                      _buildLoginBtn(),
                      _buildSignupBtn(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: exemplo da tela]

Comment: Olhando pelo código, não consegui ver algo que faria esse ícone aparecer, mas só rodando o código pra debugar melhor. Você consegue postar um snippet completo que dê pra copiar e colar pra reproduzir? (tipo um main() chamando runApp com uma tela que tem só o TextField da senha - os snippets que você postou tem várias constantes e coisas definidas em outros lugares, que não permite simplesmente pegar e rodar).

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
const primaryColor = Colors.deepPurple;
const secondaryColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
const bgColor = Color(0xFF212332);
const defaultPadding = 16.0;
final kHintTextStyle = TextStyle(
color: Colors.purpleAccent,
fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
);final kLabelStyle = TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontFamily: 'OpenSans',);
final kBoxDecorationStyle = BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFF6CA8F1),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12,blurRadius: 6.0,offset: Offset(0, 2),),],);

Comment: void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'WSPro Painel',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme
          (Theme.of(context).textTheme)
            .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
        canvasColor: secondaryColor,
      ),
      home: Login()
      );
   }}

Comment: é só adicionar esses dois codigos

Comment: eu percebi q isso só aparece na versão web